# Channel Polls not showing answer

Tags: channel-polls

I've just installed Channel Polls to test, but find that the answers do not display in the poll. Radio buttons are visible but not the label. when submitting a form this error message displays: No Answer form field found!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Edit:

I set up a clean local install of EE to test, using the same version as the client site: 2.7.3. And used the following template code:

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="poll"}
            {exp:channel_polls:new_vote entry_id="1"}
            <ul>
            {poll:answers}
            <li><input type="radio" name="{poll:form_name}" value="{poll:form_value}">   {poll:answer}</li>
            {/poll:answers}
            </ul>
            {if poll:closed}<h4>POLL CLOSED</h4>{/if}
            {if poll:no_access}<h4>YOU HAVE NO ACCESS</h4>{/if}
            {if poll:already_voted}<h4>ALREADY VOTED</h4>{/if}
            {if poll:not_voted}<h4>NOT VOTED YET</h4>{/if}
            <input name="submit" value="VOTE" type="submit">
            {/exp:channel_polls:new_vote}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

CP is version 2.7.5a. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post your template code? Did you read over the documentation for Polls? It's a pretty straightforward add-on to use as long as you have if configured properly. What versions of EE and CP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into this issue recently. In my case, I had a field named "poll" which was causing a variable collision.